# python combining 2 regexes that search strings within single and double quotes

Tags: python, regex, quotes

I have a regex that extracts *everything* between 2 double quotes and another regex that does the same for 2 single quotes.  The strings within the quotes can include escaped quotes.  I'd like to make these 2 expressions into a single one:

1)   re.findall(r'"(.*?)(?`<`!\)"', string)

2)   re.findall(r"'(.*?)(?`<`!\)'", string)

So something like:

1+2)  re.findall(r"'|\"(?`<`!\)['|\"]", string)

but this isn't working.

I'd like to have 'abc\"\"'  "abc\'\'" be evaluated using the same regex.
'abc\"\"" isn't expected to work. If the quotes were exchanged, allow the same regex to work on it also.  Is it possible?

Comment: regular expressions cannot match inside escaped quotes vs outside quotes, you will need a char-by-char parsing to do this correctly for all cases. Granted some cases will be parsed by a regex, but most will break

Comment: consider a quote escaped multiple times like `"\\\""` this will not be parsed correctly by a regex

Comment: you should keep in mind that regular expressions although powerful, cannot do some things like count opening and closing parentheses, because they do not keep state, since this is a similar problem (counting escaped quotes and matching start/end quote) the same applies

Comment: Let's say it is possible to some extent, and it is highly dependent on the input text. If it is some regular code with no comments, [it is possible I believe](https://regex101.com/r/eK9vF3/1). If there is any irregularity, [then it won't work](https://regex101.com/r/eK9vF3/2). And it would be much easier with `‘’`, `“”`, `«»`...

Answer (score 0):

not sure i understood exactly what you wanted but it is possible to reuse the value of captured group in a regex.
may the following pattern do the job:
**(['"])(.*)\1**

explanation:
**(['"])** : a quote or double-quote is captured as first group
**(.*)** : the second group captures everything... 
**\1** : ...until the first group value is met again
the result is available in the second group